# How to plot a generalized function?

Tags: graphing-functions, distribution-theory

When we are dealing with regular functions, one thing we can do with them is to plot them. We would draw $y$ and $x$ coordinate axes, draw some line and would say that the line represents some function $y(x)$.

When we are dealing with distributions, we call them generalized functions. If we call them functions, there ought to be a way to draw them. But I can't figure out how to do that.

Consider, for instance, a Dirac delta distribution of a test function $\phi$:
$$\delta (x-a) [\phi]  \equiv \phi(a)$$
It matches the function $\phi$ with its value at $x=a$. Therefore, in order to plot it I have to assign the vertical axis to $\phi(a)$ (ordinates) and the horizontal axis to $\phi$ (abscissas).

Since $\phi(a)$ is scalar I understand perfectly well how to put its values on the vertical axis.

But for the life of me I can't understand what it means to put function $\phi$ on the horizontal axis.

I'm wondering how mathematicians plot generalized functions and if they don't then what the usual discussion about this peculiarity is.

Comment: Since distributions eat functions and spit out numbers, they're not functions in the sense that one has in mind when wanting to draw a graph. Even more broadly, "function" is an abstract concept which is not the same as a graph, and not every function is going to be easily drawable.

Comment: One way to view distributions is as objects which emphasize *local properties* of functions.

Comment: Thank you @cmk. Just to put it explicitly: there's no way to plot them, nobody does that and nobody needs that. Is that correct?

Comment: Most commonly used distributions are ordinary piecewise continuous functions, just with a specific interpretation of integration. One such example is $\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}$. Then we have distributions like $\delta(x)$ and $\delta'(x)$ which only live at $x=0$. These are probably best graphed as an ordinary function that approximates the distribution.

Comment: As said in the comments, various important examples of distributions come from more traditional functions, in which case you define the distributional action on a function by integrating the product of the two functions. For an generic distribution, you likely necessarily do this, though (although things like approximation and structure theorems exist). I'd say that it doesn't serve significant purpose to plot them, though (especially in higher dimensions).

Answer (score 2):

First, for just Dirac deltas at various locations, I graph them by drawing an arrow up or down at the location, maybe labelled by a constant coefficient. This has helped me, and seems to help some other people, understand that the derivative of Heaviside's step function is Dirac delta (at 0) without having to integrate by parts.

Also, and for more complicated distributions, I do find it useful to draw classical-function approximations. This can be useful to understand derivative-taking and such (since, after all, the weak-dual limit of distributional/classical derivatives is the distributional derivative of the weak-dual limit).

Comment: Thank you. Drawing Dirac delta is more or less understandable. But drawing a Dirac delta distribution is not. I'm wondering if you can add a drawing of a classical-function approximation to your answer please (I mean approximation to the example I provided in my question, or any other example at your choice).